# Chaining of Wiremock Responses

Tags: tdd, wiremock

I'm currently working on Spring Boot app. AS part of that I'm using TDD throughout to prove that my changes are correct. To do this I'm using Wiremock to replicate an external API. I'm wondering is it possible to chain multiple responses like you would with something Mockito (like below):

```
when(myMock.doTheCall())
.thenReturn("You failed")
.thenReturn("Success");
```

Would a WiremockRule have something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally WireMock will return same response for any request matched the same way. If you wish to have different response the second time you have to use stateful behaviour: http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/ . Another alternative is to generate dynamic responses with the help of extensions: http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/ .

So the answer to your question is **NO**, not out of the box.

If your tests become clumsy because of that you might want to extract some helpers/wrappers around WireMock.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm using stateful behavior at the moment. I was looking to see could i simply my tests even further.